# Add Extra Column in View for DataTable Paging using Ajax in ASP.Net MVC or Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using DataTable in Item listing page in ASP.Net Core website. Due to high volume of data I need to change the mechanism of load records. Now I want to load records for specific page. I am able to get data using following code but I don't know how to add extra column which has hyperlinks and that call actions.

Please guide me.

Code: Index.cshtml

```
<table id="tblData" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MinimumQty)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OnHandQuantity)
            </th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>TransactionReport</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @*@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MinimumQty)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OnHandQuantity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ItemID">Edit</a>
                    <span>|</span>
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ItemID">Delete</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="TransactionReport" asp-route-id="@item.ItemID">View</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }*@
    </tbody>
</table>

@section Scripts{
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
           var table = $('#tblData').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 2,
                "paging": true,
                ajax: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetItemsDataTable","Items")',
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: "json"
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: "ItemName"},
                    { data: "MinimumQty"},
                    { data: "OnHandQuantity"},
                ],
                serverSide: "true",
                order: [0, "asc"],
                processing:"true",
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a 'serverside' way of implementation,

First, add a recursive method that has an offset, and fetch parameters.
These parameters will be used in getting all the items in your datatatable.

Second, on your datatable columns, add an object action, and transcriptReport

`{data: 'Action'}, {data: transcriptReport}`

Third, on your recursive method, use a Promise that returns the offset-fetched data from your db or just use Ajax.

Everytime your recursive method gets data from the server, use

```
datatable.rows.add(data).draw();
```